# phpexcel file download issue

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am using the `05featuredemo.php` example of the phpexcel, which is downloaded from the [codeplex](http://www.phpexcel.codeplex.com) Latest Built `PHPExcel_1.8.0_doc`  by [MarkBaker](https://www.codeplex.com/site/users/view/MarkBaker) ([SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/324584/mark-baker))

The point i need i look is

```
$objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xls', __FILE__));
```

Above is used for saving the file in the script location, But How can i make it as simple downloadable.

I tried with

```
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

But It didn't download the file that is generated. How can i do that, Is there any other thing i should do ?

Comment: Did saving the file in a normal way work? When you tried what `php://output`, what happened? Did you see anything in the browser, did you get an error?

Comment: I tried with `php://output` and nothing happened. and now i am trying with headers, Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're sending anything other than straight HTML to a browser, then you need to send the appropriate headers so that the browser can know how to handle it.

There is a section of the developer documentation entitled [Redirect output to a client’s web browser](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/08-Recipes.md#redirect-output-to-a-clients-web-browser) that explains this, and it's also demonstrated in examples like `01simple-download-xls.php` and `01simple-download-xlsx.php`

Comment: Thanks i am trying to send with headers

Comment: I tried with **Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel5)** as mentioned in the **01simple-download-xls.php** But the file downloaded asks to **Create new PHPExcel object** and unreadable texts inside, :( Here is my Code http://paste.ofcode.org/tuPYZRyc8zbSBhrjCCZWkz

Comment: If you look at the `05featuredemo.inc.php` file, you'll see that it echoes information to the screen at various points.... read the cautionary note in the section of the documentation that I referenced about any information being echoed.... then comment out all those echo statements in `05featuredemo.inc.php` and try again

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give name by yourself then you can specify as I have specified in `$a`.

I wanted to use a filename from where this function is being called so I concat that name to the excel filename and also attached current date to the filename.

Note: `LogReport` is a folder where my files will be downloaded.

```
self::$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter(self::$objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
        $a = 'Log' . self::$filename . date("Y-m-d") . '.xlsx';
        $objWriter->save(__DIR__ . '/LogReport/' . $a);
```